# Issues with mobile menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I guess this isn't a specific enough question, but i was hoping someone could advise me on how to debug a failing mobile side menu.

So my main site which is a wordpress site works perfectly but my offsite white label doesn't.

I have copied the html to the white label and added all the css and scripts from the header and footer also.

Everything looks correct and is styled nicely and the hamburger menu even changes the icon on click, so i can safely assume that the scripts are loading correctly.

My main site is http://lowcosttravel.ie and the failing page is http://hotel.lowcosttravel.ie

I don't expect anyone to just fix this for me but if someone could advice on how to debug to find which part is not loading correctly.

I'm aware of CORS issues on some font icons but i'm not concerned with those at present.

Kind regards and many thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You've made some changes to the structure HTML and changed class names. You have probably not not reflected these changes in the CSS and JavaScript/jQuery. You are also probably not targeting the correct element with JavaScript/jQuery to set display:block on the menu wrapper.

On http://hotel.lowcosttravel.ie/ your mobile menu wrapper is called hamburger-menu-wrapper where as on http://lowcosttravel.ie/ it is called wrapper-mobile-nav.

Changing hamburger-menu-wrapper to wrapper-mobile-nav http://hotel.lowcosttravel.ie/ in the inspect appears to open the menu wrapper.

I would go and see what your JavaScript/jQuery is targeting and make the appropriate changes

Answer (score -1):

I think you forgot to copy **Menu Mobile HTML** from http://lowcosttravel.ie to http://hotel.lowcosttravel.ie. The below screenshot taking from http://lowcosttravel.ie and i'm unable to find this HTML in your failing page http://hotel.lowcosttravel.ie/. I hope this will help you out. Thanks

[image]